# Android google maps crashes :com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps

Yesterday (23.04.2020) our Firebase started reporting a lot of google maps library bugs:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on and how to work around it?

Comment: We have the same problem for about 1-2 days.
I don't think there is any solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug on Google's side, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417

There is a workaround you can do there, or wait for a forthcoming update to Google Play Services.